# SAP JCo 3 RFC RSAQ_REMOTE_QUERY_CALL - unexpected results

Tags: jco, sap-r3, sap-query

We’re using JCo 3.0 to connect to RFCs and read data from SAP R/3.  We use one RFC RFC_READ_TABLE often and use a second custom RFC to read employee information.  My questions revolve around a third RFC RSAQ_REMOTE_QUERY_CALL.  I'm calling an ad-hoc query I built in SAP using this RFC but I’m not getting the expected results.  The main problem is that it appears that SAP is ignoring one of my selection criteria and using what was saved in SAP when I originally built it.  The date criterion stored in my ad-hoc is 6/23/2013.  If I pass in 6/28/2013 from JCo, I get the same results as if I had passed 6/23/2013 from JCo.

We have built several ad-hoc queries whose only criteria is a personnel number and call them successfully using RFC RSAQ_REMOTE_QUERY_CALL.

Background on my ad-hoc query: reporting period of today, joining together four aspects of an employee’s information: their latest action (hire, rehire, etc.), organization (e.g. company), pay (e.g. pay scale level) and communication (e.g. email).  The query will run every workday.

Here are my questions:

1. My ad-hoc has three selection criteria.  The first two are simple strings.  The third is a date.  The date will vary each time the query runs.  We are referencing the first criteria using SP$00001, the second with SP$00002 and the third with SP$00003.  The order of the criteria changes from the ad-hoc to SQ01 (what was SP$00001 in the ad-hoc is now SP$00003).  Shouldn’t we reference them in the order defined in the ad-hoc (e.g. SP$00001)?
2. The two simple string selections are using OPTION “EQ”.  The date criteria is using OPTION GT (greater than).  Is “GT” correct?
3. We have some limited accessibility to SAP.  Is there a way to see which SP$ parameters are mapped to which criteria?
4. If my ad-hoc was saved with five criteria but four of them never change when I call the ad-hoc from JCo, do I just need to set the value of the one or do I need to set the other four as well?
5. Do I have to call this ad-hoc using a variant (function.getImportParameterList().setValue(“VARIANT”, “VARIANT_NAME”))?
6. Does the Reporting Period have an impact on the date criteria?  I have tried changing the Reporting Period to be PNPBEGDA = today and PNPENDDA = today and noticed no change.
7. Is there a way in SAP to get a “declaration” of your ad-hoc (name, inputs, outputs, criteria)?  I have looked at JCoFunction.toXml() and JCoFunctionTemplate.  These are good if you want to see something at runtime before it goes to SAP, but I’m looking for something I can use on the JCo end to help me write Java code that matches the ad-hoc.

I have looked at length on the web for answers to my questions and have not found anything that is useful.  If there is anything which would help me, please let me know.

Thanks,

LM

Comment: It looks like either the query has been written to default in 6/23/2013, or that you are executing with a default variant where 6/23/2013 has been saved to the date.

Comment: How can I tell I've written it to default to 6/26/2013?  I didn't know there was such a thing as a default variant.  Is a default variant created each time the ad-hoc is saved?

Comment: In SQ01, you can use the menu path Goto->Maintain variants.  Check if any of the variants have the date saved.  I'm not that well versed with the query tools, so I'm not entirely sure where you would enter a default for a selection field :(

Comment: @Esti: I went to the path you mentioned in SQ01 and found the "standard" variant alive and well.  It had a date in it, so I deleted it.  I re-ran my JCo and I got back over 12K employees (it acted like there was no date criteria at all even though I passed it one). I deleted the variant, but my JCo got the error "no variant", so it thinks it needs a variant even though I commented out "setValue("VARIANT","VARIANT_NAME")". I re-created the STANDARD variant with no selection criteria and passed in everything. Now at least I don't get the "no variant" error but it is ignoring all my critieria.

Comment: Ok, it looks like there's still a problem with passing the date through from JCo.  Unfortunately I have never done that.  Do you have any way to put a break-point in your query so you can see what comes through from JCo?  I'm wondering if you are perhaps using a date format that SAP does not recognise.  Unfortunately it doesn't look like I will be much help from here, but you may want to try a few different date formats.  You've already tried MM/DD/YYYY, you may want to try: DD/MM/YYYY; YYYY/MM/DD; MM.DD.YYYY; DD.MM.YYYY and YYYY.MM.DD.  You could also try it without the delimiter.

Comment: The format I'm using is YYYYMMDD - we've used that format querying SE16 and the various infotypes with no problem. But... you never know.  I'll try other formats just to cover all my bases. Unfortunately, I can't set a breakpoint and see what's being passed from JCo to SAP. That would be too easy! I have played more with the SAP variant. I can set the date criteria to not be passed in at all any more but be calculated on the fly by SAP (current date minus one business day), but that defeats the whole purpose of passing in parameters. I'll keep working on it. You've been very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record: standard date format used by JCo is YYYY-MM-DD. When transferred via RFC protocol, the value is then shortened to YYYYMMDD.

Also in the above you are saying "we are using an RFC". This is wrong: you are using an RFM!
- RFC is the name of the protocol ("Remote Function Call")
- RFM is the thing that you execute via this protocol ("Remote-enabled Function Module")
Similar difference as in "HTTP" and "URL". No one would say "I'm executing an HTTP", everyone would say "I'm executing a URL"... HTTP is the name of the protocol and a URL is the thing that can be called

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know much about `SQnn`, I won't be able to answer all of your questions...

1. I don't know, sorry.
2. It should be, at least it's the usual operator for greater than.
3. Yes - set an external breakpoint right inside the function module and trace its execution while performing the RFC call. Warning: At least basic ABAP knowledge required.
4. I don't know, sorry.
5. I don't know either, sorry.
6. That would depend on the query, I suspect...
7. JCo won't be able to help you out there - it doesn't know about queries, it only knows function modules. There might be other `RSAQ_*` function modules to get that information though.

Comment: 1. thanks anyway.
2. thanks - appreciate it!
3. unfortunately, we don't have full SAP ABAP access and can't debug.  We can build ad-hocs, but at runtime we really only can see things from the client end.
4, 5, 6. no problem.
7. I was just curious more than anything else.  It would just make things a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I played with setting up a variant in SQ01 for my query. I added some settings in the variant that solved my problem and answered several of my questions in my post. The main thing I did was add a dynamically calculated date as part of my criteria.  Here's how:
1. In SQ01, access menu "Go To" -> "Maintain Variants".
2. Choose your variant and in subobjects, choose "Attributes" and click "Change".
3. In the displayed list, find your date criterion.
4. Choose "D" in Selection Variable, choose a comparison option (mine was GT for greater than), and a "Name of a Variable" (really, this is the type of dynamic date calculation you need).
5. Go back to the Subobjects panel, choose "Values" and click "Change".
6. Enter any other criteria you need in the "Program selections" section.
7. Save the variant.
By doing this, I don't need to pass anything into the query from JCo. Also, SAP will automatically update the date criteria you entered in step #4 above.
So to to answer my questions from my original post:
1 and 4. It doesn't matter because I'm no longer passing anything in from JCo.
2. "GT" is Greater Than.
3 and 7. If anyone knows, I'd really like to find out.
5. Use the name you as it is in SAP (step #2 above).
6. I still don't know, but it's not holding me up.
I'm posting this in case anyone out there needs this type of information.  Thanks to Esti and vwegert for helping me out.